# Django rest swagger nested serializer showing list of array in Example UI

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

Django Rest Swagger is not able to parse the Inner Serializer as an array of objects instead it shows only list of string

My Serializers:

```
class InfluencerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     prices = PriceSerializer(many=True)
     first_name = serializer.CharField(max_length=100)

class PriceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     cost = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
```

On Swagger UI it appears as below json in Example

```
{ 
  "first_name": "string", 
  "prices": ["string"],
}
```

While I am expected Swagger UI to show
    { 
      "first_name": "string", 
      "prices": [
           {"cost":0}
       ],
    }

I am using

```
Django==1.10.6
djangorestframework==3.6.1
django-rest-swagger==2.1.2
```

Comment: Were you able to debug the issue?

Comment: Nested serializers are not supported by ``django-rest-swagger``. https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg could help you (disclaimer: I'm the author of this library).

Answer (score 4):

django-rest-swagger does not support nested serializers and lists ([ref](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/663)), use [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/) instead